# I cannot install module with pip

Tags: python, module, pip, python-3.8

After installing python 3.8, I cannot install module with `pip`:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/enum34-1.1.10.dist-info'
Check the permissions.
```

Comment: _Did_ you check the permissions on this folder? Maybe you previously used `sudo` on an install which created the `~/.local/lib/python3.8` folder as `root`, and now you can't access it _without_ `sudo` anymore... Maybe you want to `chown -R` the whole folder to you.

Comment: Yes, I did that before

Comment: Can you also show the command you gave when you received this error? If your command was with sudo you shouldn't have had permission issues.

Comment: for example: pip3 install notebook *******            I want to use pip without sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `sudo` in the beginning of the command if you are in linux. Maybe you are bot using the system as a root

Comment: I want to change the installation path of the modules. How can I do this?

Comment: You can change the installation path by using the -t flag and then providing the path.

Comment: Can you give me an example so that I can better understand what you mean?

Comment: sudo pip install module -t ./path/where/uwantti/install

Comment: When searching error try copying the whole error and pasting it on google, that helps alot

Comment: You got it, have you removed your error. Then please marked my answer as answered

Answer (score 0):

Add `--user` at the end

```
pip3 install package_name --user
```

Comment: No, I tried this, but unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use anaconda with the following command in the terminal:

```
conda install -c anaconda pip
```

If you don't have anaconda:

```
pip install conda
```